# Why a powershell command is valid in the terminal but invalid from lnk file?

Tags: powershell

For example, this command works perfectly from a PowerShell prompt :

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -c Set-Variable -Name "CA_HOME" -Value "$(Get-Location).Path\intermed-ca"
```

but fails with an error if used from an lnk file.

```
Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '\intermed-ca'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Variable -Name CA_HOME -Value $(Get-Location).Path'\intermed-ca'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Variable], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand
```

Why ?

Comment: Why are you using `powershell.exe -NoExit -c` in a 'PowerShell prompt'?

Comment: It's easier and quicker to test from a terminal, compared to a .lnk file, could have been powershell ISE or visual studio.

Comment: You specifically said that "this command works perfectly from a PowerShell prompt" and provided a command which specifically runs a command in another powershell instance. In order for both the 'shortcut' command, and the 'prompt' command, to be comparative, your shortcut would need to open a powershell prompt, then run the powershell command in another instance of powershell too. So please tell us what exactly the command that you've used in your shortcut is. If it is exactly the same as that which you've used in an alreadty opened powershell prompt window, they are clearly not the same.

Comment: The command is as seen in the question, powershell.exe -NoExit -c Set-Variable -Name "CA_HOME" -Value "$(Get-Location).Path\intermed-ca", i want to know why the command does not work if run from a .lnk file, i'm not even asking how to make it work/correct it to make it work from a shortcut file, just the technical reason it does not work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you supplied is not from that particular command. Notice PowerShell is showing us the command it is erroring on.

That particular error is simply a syntax error; that is not how you concatenate strings. Running just `$(Get-Location).Path'\intermed-ca'` will give you an error: "Unexpected token ''\intermed-ca'' in expression or statement."

Going back to the command you posted at the top of the OP, that is proper syntax, but won't be the Path you're looking for because the logic is flawed. So, what you posted as your command will not generate an error, but will return a path that likely doesn't exist. Assuming your *working directory* is your user profile, you will get something like this back for `$CA_HOME`: `C:\Users\Zulgrib.Path\intermed-ca`. The reason is that you're basically doing this:

```
$path = (Get-Location).Path
'{0}.Path\intermed-ca' -f $path
```

The `.Path` is part of the string, not the string execution. That's why you should add parenthesis to ensure that this property is returned as part of the string execution:

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -c Set-Variable -Name "CA_HOME" -Value "$((Get-Location).Path)\intermed-ca"
```

While this is fine and will work without issues, **quote translations can be tricky from the command line.** So, this really isn't a perfect solution for all scenarios. For better compatibility, I would get in the habit of wrapping the whole command in double quotes and keep single quotes inside the command:

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -c "Set-Variable -Name 'CA_HOME' -Value ('{0}\intermed-ca' -f (Get-Location).Path)"
```

For the best compatibility, consider base64 encoding your command and running it with `-EncodedCommand`. See the very bottom of `powershell.exe /?` for an example. Be weary that some situations will run into issues with overly long CLI commands.

Note: `'{0}\intermed-ca' -f (Get-Location).Path` and `'{0}\intermed-ca' -f (Get-Location)` will give the same result. When PowerShell knows it's injecting a PSOobject into a string, it'll give you the string form of what you likely want.

Comment: Set as answer but missing technical reasons it did not work, will switch answer status if someone come up with a more extended explanation on this part.